# Mi ciclo for se salta el primer registro

Tags: php, bucle-for, bucles, fpdf

Estoy imprimiendo un reporte en pdf con la libreria fpdf con código en php, pero al imprimirlo el ciclo for se salta el primer registro, mostrando únicamente del segundo en adelante, me gustaría saber en dónde está mi error y por qué inicializa en el segundo registro.

```
<?php

class PDF extends FPDF {
var $widths;
var $aligns;
var $lineHeight;
function SetWidths($w){
    $this->widths=$w;
}
function SetAligns($a){
    $this->aligns=$a;
}
function SetLineHeight($h){
    $this->lineHeight=$h;
}
function Row($data)
{
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
        $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
    }
    $h=$this->lineHeight * $nb;
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
        $this->MultiCell($w,5,$data[$i],0,$a);
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
    }
    $this->Ln($h);
}
function CheckPageBreak($h)
{
    if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
        $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
}
function NbLines($w,$txt)
{
    $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb=strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 and $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $sep=-1;
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $l=0;
    $nl=1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        $c=$s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            $i++;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
            $sep=$i;
        $l+=$cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
            }
            else
                $i=$sep+1;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    return $nl;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Tienes varios ciclos. ¿Cuál es el que se lo salta según tú? ¿Depuraste que no sea un defecto de los datos, o sea que ese registro que crees que está ahí no está realmente?

Comment: comprueba el valor de $this->widths[0]. Prueba a prefijar $w y $h a un valor de test.